# Creating a report with continuous dates from discontinous data in Database with linq and Entity Framework core 5

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to build a report from some data in my database. It is a list of items representing the income per day in our systems. Our data is stored hourly so, a group by the date part of a datetime is used. Here the query:

```
dateDataQuery = query.GroupBy(o => new {o.Time.Month, o.Time.Year, o.Time.Day})
    .OrderBy(o => o.Key.Year).ThenBy(o => o.Key.Month).ThenBy(o => o.Key.Day)
    .Select(g => new StatData()
    {
        Day = g.Key.Day,
        Month = g.Key.Month,
        Income = g.Sum(o => o.Income),
    });
```

This works correctly but the problem is that if we have a day with no transactions, there wouldn't be any record in the database for this day and so, the StatData object for this day would not appear in the result.

This is a problem because this data will be represented in a graph in our frontend and needs to be continuous. I mean, every date at a day resolution must appear in the result at least with an Income of 0.

So, is there any possibility to do this with Entity framework core and linq without having to go through all the returned data, and check if date exists manually?

Comment: EF will not do that for you. You have to post process data and inject in result missed values and apply approximation formula to missed records.

Comment: Yup, just wanted confirmation for it in case I was missing something. Thanks.

Comment: the missing data is not in any tables which means to fill in the gaps, you need some data (auto-generated) no matter it's on server side (processed by DB engine) or app side (in-memory). So in this case, if writing the sql code, you may need some CTE or temp table to join with the existing data for filling the gaps. That logic is similar if done on the app side. The only benefit of trying to do it on the DB engine is to support paging conveniently. If you don't need paging, just better do it on the app side. I believe paging implementation on the app side is OK but may be fairly complicated.